# allocate maximum memory on heap

Tags: c++, heap-memory

I want to know how a program can allocate the maximum amount of memory using new[] before throwing an error message for the final allocation, just like

```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;
   int main()
   {
   try
   {
      do
      {
      int i = new int;
      throw sth;
      .......
      }while(true);
   }
   catch(Exception){
    cerr<<"out of range"<<endl;
   }
    return 0;
   }
```

something like this. I am really struck in this problem and working on this for a long time. A sample algorithm of how to do this may also be much appreciated.
help me please
Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Your code is not valid C++ 2. Why don't you try it yourself? 3. Hint: this is platform dependent.

Comment: The code you have posted is not even valid C++.  Can you try a bit harder to show us a program that at least compiles and runs?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this, I am a bit new to programming world

Comment: That sounds like a funny question from someone who's new to programming. Why do you want to do that? Curiosity? Or is there an actual practical problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: This is a actual practical problem that I'm struggling to solve. If anyone have an idea how an algorithm will be or any link can help my issue

Comment: "actual practical problem" doesn't include people solving your homework for you.

Comment: @anu "actual practical problem" would be "how do I find out how much memory does the system have". I can't think of a single practical purpose for what you asked, though.

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like this?

```
size_t s = 0;
char* p = nullptr;
while(p = new (std::nothrow) char[++s]) delete[] p;
std::cout << "Max successful heap allocation: " << s - 1 << " bytes." << std::endl;
```

Comment: thanks for the help, when I tried to compile these lines, my system command prompt is blank, without displaying anything

Comment: @anu Did you put them in your `main` function and `#include` the right headers (i.e. `<iostream>` and `<new>`)?

Comment: yes I did,#include <iostream>
#include "conio.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{char* p = nullptr;
while(p = new (std::nothrow) char[++s]) delete [] p;
std::cout << "Max successful heap allocation: " << s - 100 << std::endl;

 _getch();
}

Comment: I thought like it isn't working when I subtract 1 from it so I used -100 to see whether it is works for this or not

Comment: @anu The code as written will take a very long time to fail an allocation on most modern computers.  You can speed things up significantly by doing a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) for the failure size instead.

Comment: I have modified with your instruction, can you look at this and provide some kind of an idea size_t s = 0;
int* p = nullptr;
int low = 0;
int high = numeric_limits<int>::max();
while(p = new (std::nothrow) int[++s])
 {
  if(high<low)
   return -1;
  else
  {
   int mid = (low+high)/2;
   if(mid > s)
   // I am struck herre how can we use this for heap allocation failure, any ideas
  }
  delete [] p;
}
std::cout << "Max successful heap allocation: " << s - 1 << std::endl;

Comment: It looks like you're going in the wrong direction and possibly misunderstanding some of the core aspects of a binary search.  Try solving a simpler binary search problem, then once you're comfortable with it, come back and apply it to finding the size limit for a heap allocation.